# join tables from different databases only adding most recent date SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am joining lots of data to handle dynamic/complex querying. The following is just a part of what I'm doing. I found a solution, then I think I tweaked it and lost it.

Database Structure:

```
phpMyAdmin
|
|-oath
|    -users
|    -users_meta
|    -users_jobs
|
|-order
|    -orders
|    -carts
|    -driver_status
```

oauth.users

```
id | foo | baa
--------------
1  | x   | x 
2  | x   | x 
3  | x   | x 
4  | x   | x 
5  | x   | x
```

order.orders ( I know bad naming, I didn't create the database)

(customer_id = user.id)

```
id|order_date| customer_id| ray
-------------------------------
1 | 10/11/21 |     1      | x 
2 | 10/11/21 |     1      | x 
3 | 09/11/21 |     1      | x 
4 | 12/11/21 |     1      | x 
5 | 10/11/21 |     2      | x 
6 | 12/11/21 |     2      | x 
7 | 14/11/21 |     2      | x
```

I want to join only the most recent date

```
id | foo | baa |order_date| baa
--------------------------------
1  |  x  |  x  | 12/11/21 | x 
2  |  x  |  x  | 14/11/21 | x
```

This is my query but something went wrong. Apologize Sql Isn't my strong point, the results were multiple of the same users with different order dates were showing. If there were multiple of the most recent order_date then there would be multiple entries of that.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    oauth.users u
LEFT JOIN order.orders o
ON
    o.customer_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MAX(order_date) order_date
    FROM order.orders o2
    GROUP BY
        customer_id
) SubQ
ON
    SubQ.customer_id = o.customer_id AND SubQ.order_date = o.order_date
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin, and I think it uses Mysql / mariasql

Comment: What is th eproblem with your query?

Comment: "Something went wrong" isn't helpful. It looks like it should work, so explain what went wrong. Did you get an error message?

Comment: Amended with the problem it occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM oauth.users oa
LEFT JOIN (SELECT oo.customer_id, oo.order_date  FROM order.orders oo
INNER  JOIN (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        MAX(`order_date`) order_date
    FROM order.orders o2
    GROUP BY
        customer_id
) oo2 ON oo.customer_id = oo2.customer_id AND oo2.order_date = oo.order_date) t1
ON
    t1.customer_id = oa.id
```

see example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c6bbca/12

Comment: The query is right but I think you should change `left join` to `right join` based on required result

Comment: the table structure is not the same as tzhe result and so i think he wants all users not only the ones that have an order. Buut this answer should help to get ti the right result

Comment: I want to return all users even if they don't have an order_date

Comment: @SamuelMorgan-Tyghe that is what my code does.

Comment: Thanks @nbk I'll check it out soon, I was just clarifying to ergest

Comment: @nbk 
The code above returned this:

#1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Comment: you have to adept to your database i used the columns as you showed them in your sample

Comment: @nbk, I've rewritten this question because I require an added complexity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69584472/join-table-but-retain-every-row-in-one-column-in-sql-from-a-table-of-users-add

Comment: the badis that my answer provides is enough to solve all your problems. think about it how it works and you will grasp also your other